# How to check whether to add a symbol at the opening of a frame, and STOP if added?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I am almost done with my flash game, where ducks fall from the top of the screen and are caught in a basket. This code I have basically checks if they are in the basket when they hit a certain Y value, and if so, loops them back to the top of the screen. IF NOT, it sets a boolean `isOver` to `true`. I am trying to add a `gameOver` menu at this time, by checking at the end of a frame whether `isOver` has been set to true. My problem, is that this is an `onEnterFrame` function, so it loops the stupid menu continuously. (adding infinite instances of the menu)

Here is my code (for the `onEnterFrame` function)

```
  function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    if (isOver)
    {

        var overScreen = new over_screen();//adds the game over screen
        overScreen.x = 240;
        overScreen.y = 355;

        var againButton = new again_button();//adds the play again button
        againButton.x = 125;
        againButton.y = 415;

        var rateButton = new again_button();// adds the rate button
        rateButton.x = 360;
        rateButton.y = 415;

        addChild(overScreen);
        addChild(againButton);//adds the objects created above
        addChild(rateButton);
        stop(); //SHOULD stop the frame... I think? This is my problem
    }

    if (! isPaused && ! isOver) // the running code of the game, as long as it isnt paused or over
    {

        duck1.y +=  5;
        duck2.y +=  5;
        duck3.y +=  5;
        duck4.y +=  5;
        duck5.y +=  5;
        duck6.y +=  5;

        if (duck1.y > 620)
        {
            if (duck1.x < basket1.x + 50 && duck1.x > basket1.x - 50)
            {
                duck1.y = -50;
                duck1.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                numScore++;
                score.text = numScore.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                isOver = true;
            }

        }
        if (duck2.y > 620)
        {
            if (duck2.x < basket1.x + 50 && duck2.x > basket1.x - 50)
            {
                duck2.y = -50;
                duck2.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                numScore++;
                score.text = numScore.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                isOver = true;
            }

        }
        if (duck3.y > 620)
        {
            if (duck3.x < basket1.x + 50 && duck3.x > basket1.x - 50)
            {
                duck3.y = -50;
                duck3.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                numScore++;
                score.text = numScore.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                isOver = true;
            }
        }
        if (duck4.y > 620)
        {
            if (duck4.x < basket1.x + 50 && duck4.x > basket1.x - 50)
            {
                duck4.y = -50;
                duck4.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                numScore++;
                score.text = numScore.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                isOver = true;
            }
        }
        if (duck5.y > 620)
        {
            if (duck5.x < basket1.x + 50 && duck5.x > basket1.x - 50)
            {
                duck5.y = -50;
                duck5.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                numScore++;
                score.text = numScore.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                isOver = true;
            }
        }
        if (duck6.y > 620)
        {
            if (duck6.x < basket1.x + 50 && duck6.x > basket1.x - 50)
            {
                duck6.y = -50;
                duck6.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                numScore++;
                score.text = numScore.toString();
            }
            else
            {
                isOver = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy solution to this issue is to make your flash game have 2 frames:

in the first frame you load your menu in the onLoad Function.
second frame would have the gameplay code, and when you die you just return back to the first frame.

Comment: I was thinking about that... I have two scenes. On for the start menu,  one for gameplay. So just another frame on the gameplay scene?